# Filtering BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get a list of colleges and their web sites from another web page.

I have gotten the input down to display the HTML for each line that I want, but I am attempting to further format the text. I only want the college name and the link to that college to be displayed. Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
url = "http://www.arizona.edu/colleges"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
universities = soup.findAll('span', {'class' : 'field-content'})
for eachuniversity in universities:
   print eachuniversity
```

And here's an example of what I get for `eachuniversity`:

```
<div class="views-field-title">
  <span class="field-content">
    <a href="/colleges/college-agriculture-life-sciences">
    <h3>College of Agriculture &amp; Life Sciences</h3>
    </a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't guess what your Python code and HTML code look like just from your text. Can you include all of the relevant code?

Comment: you're mixing single and double quotes in your first line of blockquote

Answer (score 4):

The following will get you what you're looking for. The information used to do this is easily accessible in the [BeautifulSoup documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html) ([version 4 documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)).

```
for uni in universities:
    link = uni.find("a")
    college_name = link.text
    web_page = link["href"]
```

For the first uni (your example):

```
>>> print web_page
"/colleges/college-agriculture-life-sciences"
>>> print college_name
College of Agriculture &amp; Life Sciences
```

I'll leave handling relative/absolute links and special HTML characters as an exercise for you.

---

#### How this works

From your [most recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024679/how-can-i-use-beautifulsoup-to-search-for-p-tags-inside-of-certain-spans), I gather that you're having trouble extracting tags from the `uni` object. Your `universities` variable is a collection of `Tag` objects, each a dictionary-like object that can be used to access its children. Try reading ["Navigating the Parse Tree"](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Navigating%20the%20Parse%20Tree) to get a better handle on how parsing works with BeautifulSoup.