# How to use BeautifulSoup picking up texts wanted?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

(I am a newbie in Python. Read BeautifulSoup DOC however still don't know how to use it).

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to extract some information from a webpage.

The HTML source codes of the webpage contains:

```html
<TD class=genmed align=left><A href="http://m.harveynorman.com.au/ipod-shuffle-2gb.html">1015362</A></TD>

<TD class=genmed align=left><A href="http://m.harveynorman.com.au/ipod-touch-16gb-black-and-silver.html">1056332</A></TD>

<TD class=genmed align=left><A href="http://m.harveynorman.com.au/ipod-nano-16gb.html">1016552</A></TD>
```

I want to extract all texts of web links started with "*http://*", and the numbers *1015362*, *1056332*, *1016552*.

Here is the part of the codes:

```
AA = soup.findAll(text="http:")
for BB in AA:
    print BB.renderContents()
```

How can I have BeautifulSoup picking up the texts wanted?

Comment: You may check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024415/filtering-beautifulsoup?rq=1

Comment: thanks Jakob for the direction. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for link extraction

```
for link in BeautifulSoup(page, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        print link['href']
```

for text extraction

```
text = soup.find('a').gettext()
```